# Use one directive inside another directive template in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am pretty new to Angularjs and try to implement one directive inside another directive . I have a child directive `basetext` which handle basic input events and `myTextbox` which handle other task related to input. I have made a [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PtPaDx8JpTUVEx1V58s8)  to demonstrate my problem. I have implemented as

In `html`

`<div my-textbox placeholder="'Input the value'" caption="Name:"></div>`

In `myTextbox` directive template function :

```
template: function (elem, attrs) {
        return ("<label>" + attrs.caption + "</label>\
                 <input class='inputText' basetext='' " + "placeholder=" + attrs.placeholder +"/>");
},
```

and my `basetext` directive :

```
app.directive("basetext", function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{}
        template: "<input ng-focus='isFocus()' ng-blur='isBlur()'/>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.isBlur = function () {
                alert("is blurred");
            }
            scope.isFocus = function () {
                alert("is focused");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that the `blur` event and `focus` event of `basetext` directive isn't working at all . Any suggestion to solve this problem ? Thanks

Comment: just see generated html. `basetext` put `input` with events inside input where applied this directive

Comment: ok i will try that  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the element, and you will see

[image]

template of `basetext` is inside the input tag which is invalid.

You need to put `replace: true,` property on `basetext` directive as then it will replace the element which the child directive template.

```
app.directive("basetext", function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        replace: true,
        scope:{},
        template: "<input ng-focus='isFocus()' ng-blur='isBlur()'/>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.isBlur = function () {
                alert("is blurred");
            }
            scope.isFocus = function () {
                alert("is focused");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cy3u7LLHPzFFsguf9YZQ?p=preview)

Comment: interesting, i thought that `replace` should _replace_ element, instead _extend_ it :-)

Comment: great, glad to help you :)